# With a garmin edge touring can I just ride or do I have to do a route?

Tags: garmin

I'm thinking of getting a garmin edge touring but I want to use it as a map rather than a satnav. Can I just ride and it will show where I am? Or will it always want me to take a pre-determined route? Thanks.

Comment: If you aren't going to use the "round trip routing" feature where the Touring will create a "circular" route for you, I suggest you look at the Edge 800 instead.  It can actually be bought more cheaply these days, and has more features.

Answer (score 7):

The map screen will show you your location, you aren't required to choose a route, routes are just big feature of the edge touring that Garmin focused on for that line.

Comment: Just use the screen as a moving map.

Answer (score 3):

You can also call up a pre-generated route and turn off the turn-by-turn directional functionality, thus just showing your location and relationship to the route. This has worked reasonably well for me.